# Command line - Remove directories if they contain a particular file type

Tags: bash, command-line, mingw, rm

I'd like to remove some directories if they contain .png images whilst ignoring directories that do not.

I need to use command line (I'm using MinGW).

I imagine that a solution would include `rm` and  target a directory if it contains `*.png`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find -type f -name "*.png" -printf "%h\0" | uniq -z | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
ls **/*.png | while read f; do
  dirname "$f"
done | sort -uz | xargs -0 rm -rf
```